# Add Child or Sub-Level Class to WordPress Admin Pages Table List

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to submit a patch to WordPress core and this is the outline:

**The Problem: Styling a Large WordPress Admin**

In the WordPress admin, there's a big table (`#the-list`) for the list of pages. The WordPress admin file [class-wp-posts-list-table.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L487) currently adds a bunch of classes to the individual table rows for each page. What it **does not** add is a class for the page's nesting level.

I'd like to add one because scrolling through 100+ pages is tedious, and being able to style the different levels can be very helpful for seeing where you are at a glance.

**A Possible Solution**

I'd think that a semantic way to do it would be to add a class to each row: `.level-0` for top-level pages, `.level-1` for nested items, `.level-2` for the next level of nesting, and so on. The way we could do that is:

```
if ( $post->post_parent ) {
    $count = count( get_post_ancestors($post->ID) );
    $classes .= 'level-'. $count; 
} else {
    $classes .= 'level-0';
}
```

Is this a good solution, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Re-reading this, you weren't thinking of hacking the core, were you? I'll add a relevant link bellow.

Comment: Oh no, just submitting a patch to the core.

Comment: Oh, man, I had cognitive dissonance. But then, what's the Question? A better way? That's off-topic here. The place to ask for WP development is [wordpress.se]. I removed my Answer, as it doesn't make sense given this new and essential info that you want a review to submit a patch to the core.

Comment: What the heck, just go and submit the patch. If it works, it's good. If there's a better way, a core contributor will point it out in the ticket. IMO, it's a very good idea. *Everything* you wrote here is your ticket. Oh, [core contributors](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2633) hang out at WPSE ;)

Comment: Cool, thanks. The question _was_ going to be "how the heck would I do this," but I kinda figured it out as I was writing it. I just wanted some feedback, was all. I'll go to WP Answers next time. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Nice place too: [WordPress Developers](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/110928980572284315377) at G+. Probably, you already know but if not sign in for [wp-hackers mailing list](http://lists.automattic.com/mailman/listinfo/wp-hackers/). cheers